# OSX 10.10 PHP Composer not finding required extensions intl and mcrypt

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, mcrypt, intl

I am attempting to create a cake PHP application on OSX 10.10 using the following command:

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app testapp
```

When I do I am getting the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.0, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-alpha1, 3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-beta1, 3.0.0-beta2, 3.0.0-beta3, 3.0.1, 3.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
```

I have installed the intl extension via pear/pecl but still continue to get this error.

Please someone restore my faith in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to run `php5enmod intl` to activate the PHP5 module.
Otherwise, check if you have installed `intl` to the right PHP installation on OS X: there is a standard OS X one, but if you have installed a PHP version **beside** the OS X version, check if you have the right PHP in your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: How do I find out where pear is installing extensions and where composer is looking for them?

Comment: The extensions should be in `/usr/share/php/{extension}`.
To my knowledge, Composer uses your global `php` and `php.ini` to check for extensions, which I why you need to check if your `$PATH` is running the right PHP executable.

Comment: So when I look at the /usr/share/php dir the only folder is called 'fpm' and contains a file called status.html... How do I change the default to use this one